# Can I get click methods inside vuex

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I just started learning Vue and Vuex. I saw that I have the same code in different components. I started using Vuex and i store my data inside index.js and it's really helpful.
My questions is, how can I store click functions with vuex. In the code below is simple example

```
<button  @click="clickMe">Click Me</button>

 methods: {
    clickMe() {
       console.log('Hellouu')
    },
 }
```

Comment: You can create utility file and put this `clickMe()` method in that so that you can use shared code across all the click events.

Comment: +1 on @CreativeLearner. Vuex usually used for manage state globally. for me it's better to create file for global method

Answer (score 0):

Keeping the logic of a component in itself is what component-based approach is about. A click listener on a component or its sub-element is very personal and private to a component.

### Mixins

But.. let's say you have a situation where you have the same exact logic that needs to be executed on-click on multiple components, the answer will be to use [mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html?redirect=true). **Store is not the place to do it**. This holds and is true for any case where you need to 'share reusable functionalities'.

Apart from providing flexibility, mixins have a number of benefits, for instance, you can take advantage of the [option merging](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html?redirect=true#:%7E:text=hello%20from%20mixin!%22-,Option%20Merging,-When%20a%20mixin) rules within mixins to override the onClick() method described in a mixin to cater for a special case within one of the components, but continue to use the rest of the common logic the mixin contains.

*Note: Be careful though, `Hook functions` with the same name are instead merged into an array so that all of them will be called. Mixin hooks will be called **before** the component’s own hooks.*

##### Read more (optional)

As a great real world example check out this repository: https://github.com/buefy/buefy. Its a UI components library that is built with Vuejs. You can find many more examples and best practices in such open source repositories and these are always a great reference point for writing better code.